# How do I share my connection with ICS and an Xbox 360?

Tags: 11.04, networking, internet, interface

## Update

Ok so after some playing around I found a GUI way to setup Internet Connection Sharing in ubuntu 11.04(Natty), Remembering that I am using gnome 3.

We have the *network Manager Applet* up top
[image]

*Right click* and choose *edit connections*
[image]

Under the *Wired*  tab highlight your wired connection and click *Edit...*
[image]

Under the *IPV4* tab in the *Method* dropdown select *Shared to other computers*.
[image]

Finally **restart your computer**.
Set your xbox to automatic connection settings.

### The new question...

So after getting it working the only issue is that I have a strict NAT type.

I was wondering if anyone could help me fix that?
My settings are

> Router is 192.168.1.1
>
> Wireless card is:
>    - IP: 192.168.1.3 (static)
>    - Broadcast: 192.168.1.255
>    - Subnet: 255.255.255.0
>    - DNS: 192.168.1.1
>
> The wired network sets itself as:
>    - IP: 10.42.43.1
>    - Broadcast: 10.42.43.255
>    - Subnet: 255.255.255.0
>
> The xbox sets itself as:
>    - IP: 10.42.43.31
>    - Subnet: 255.255.255.0
>    - Gateway: 10.42.43.1 (wired IP)
>    - DNS: 10.42.43.1 (wired IP)

---

I am wanting to use ICS in ubuntu (Natty) for the xbox 360.

I am struggling to find out a step by step guide to do it.

Basically The setup is

Modem -> router (ip 192.168.1.1) -> laptop (via wifi (static ip 192.168.1.3)) -> xbox (via ethernet).

For some reason it seems that my connections are also named a bit funny.

It seems that my wifi connection is eth1 and my wired is eth0.

So a step by step guide of how to configure this is what I am after.

Comment: I've always done this type of thing cli.  Troubleshooting the gui isn't my thing.  I hope you get it worked out though.

Comment: Maybe check out Firestarter [sudo apt-get install firestarter].  It's a firewall, but it also has a ICS feature.

Comment: If i am understanding correctly, the problem is your going from router to laptop over wifi and then from laptop to xbox over wired, so the ip rangers and different, and thus leaving you unable to forward. I am not near my Ubuntu right now to give you a step by step, but I can tell you I am doing this currently but with windows, as I have a broken wifi card on my laptop and an unsupported usb wifi card. So Win7 gets wifi, and then I bridged the LAN/WIFI cards and assigned my laptop (Ubuntu) a static ip. So i believe the solution to your problem will be a network bridge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that these ports aren't opened with your router.

```
Port 88 (UDP)
Port 3074 (UDP and TCP)
Port 53 (UDP and TCP)
Port 80 (TCP)
```

Open these ports and it should be fixed. Though this website incorporates windows, you should be able to modify the info to suit ubuntu.

http://www.ehow.com/how_4550488_open-router-ports.html